# Mount Docker container in Azure App Service as read-only filesystem

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

Docker has a `run` command that accepts a `--read-only` argument for mounting a container with a read-only filesystem. Is there a way to set up an Azure App Service slot to run a container from an Azure Container Registry with a read-only filesystem? I haven't been able to find any documentation or setting in the web console for configuring this.

My current setup is to use a GitHub Actions workflow to build and deploy the container with `docker/build-push-action` and `azure/webapps-deploy` Actions. My app is a Python Django app and as part of a security assessment, I've been instructed to make the app run in a read-only environment to prevent runtime modification of the app's code. I've already ensured that no part of my app needs to be able to write to the Docker container's filesystem, so now all I need to do is to ensure that the filesystem cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers for Azure App Service cannot be run in read-only mode(Mounting a Host's root File System in Read-Only Mode). [AZ CLI Azure App Service for Docker supported commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/container?view=azure-cli-latest)

You can run your app in Azure App Service directly from a ZIP package, the ZIP package itself gets mounted directly as the read-only wwwroot directory.
Running directly from a package have multiple benefits:

- Eliminates file lock conflicts between deployment and runtime.
- Ensures only full-deployed apps are running at any time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't change the docker command that the Azure App Service used to run the containers. Actually, there is nothing you can do with the command. All the containers are temporary. If you only want to run the containers and do not need to persist the data. Then you need to do nothing. The app services won't affect the filesystem after you delete them.

Comment: Good to know. I'm actually trying to block runtime modifications of the app's source code in response to a security assessment we received (I updated my question to reflect this).